# Type of ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, decimal, bigint

I want to know which type is better for Auto-ID in SQL Server

For example I have table `Comments`, user posts 100K comment each day, must I use a `bigint` or `decimal` or `GUID` for ID of comments?

Can someone explain how it works better.

Comment: With an `INT`, you get 2 billion possible values - if the user keeps posting 100K comments **each day**, that range of values is enough to handle **58.8 years** of non-stop commenting by your user.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decimal would never be a good idea. I would go with bigint for your application.

GUID is useful when you don't want ids to be sequential or you want to merge data from multiple sources or move data around without conflicts - when sharding as an example.

Basically, if you don't have a specific reason to use GUID, I would use bigint. Unless you KNOW that there isn't going to be much data in the table in which case, use int.